# strike a sword into vs swing a sword into

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> He struck a sword into the air.

If we say he struck a sword into the air, it means someone struck a sword with something other than a sword or a sword and deflected it into the air.

But if we say:

> He swung a sword into the air.

It means that he swung his sword into the air as though there was a target in his mind, imagination.

Is there a way to say that you swing a sword into the air as though you're imagining yourself fighting against an imaginary opponent since you don't have any sparring partner? I can't think of a way to say it.

Comment: And why do you need to use "strike" when you mean "swing"?

Comment: you can use strike in an intransitive manner, but if you use it transitively I can't think of a way to say it.

Comment: You could "strike at" an imaginary opponent with a sword

Comment: I like the sentence "He swung a sword at the air". It communicates exactly what is intended and requires minimal modification to the original sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He struck a sword in the air

is ambiguous and not particularly idiomatic. It may mean

> He thrust his sword into the air

or, possibly,

> He knocked someone else’s sword into the air.

And the sentence

> He swung his sword in the air

is idiomatic but vague. Depending on what you mean, better might be

> He brandished his sword above his head

or

> His sword sliced though empty air.

There is not always a single word that captures a complex idea. If there were, no book need contain more than a single word.

There are literally millions of way to say what you want.

> John thrust, lunged, ducked, twisted away, and parried vigorously against an opponent conjured up by John’s imagination.

> John practiced his swordplay against an imaginary duelist.

Adjectives and adverbs have their uses.